# C#: DataReceived Event handler for serialPort not firing

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm writing a fairly basic application, where one of the tasks is communicating with an Arduino Uno card.
I would like to write the serial communication as a separate module, so the forms only calls for the input from Arduino, and the module will handle the creating and opening of the serialPort and reading data from it.
For testing purposes I wrote a program for the Arduino which prints the elapsed milliseconds every half second to the serialPort.
I would like to populate the textBox of my Form with the output from Arduino after I press a button.
I create the serialPort in the SerialComm class, and although I attach a DataReceived event handler to it, it never seems to fire.
Here is the code for the SerialComm class:

```
class SerialComm
{
    private List<String> availablePorts;
    private SerialPort arduino;
    private string receivedText;

    public String[] portList
    { get
        {
            EnumPorts();
            return availablePorts.ToArray();
        }
    } 
    public string receivedData
    {
        get
        {
            return receivedText;
        }
    }

    public void InitialiseSerial()
    {
        arduino = new SerialPort();
        arduino.BaudRate = 9600;
        arduino.DtrEnable = true;
        // Add event handler
        arduino.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(arduino_DataReceived);
    }

    public void EnumPorts()
    {
        availablePorts = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            availablePorts.Add(s);
        }
    }

    public void StartMC(SerialPort serialPort, String portName)
    {
        arduino = serialPort;
        if (arduino.IsOpen)
        {
            arduino.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //Initialise Serial Port
            arduino.PortName = portName;        
            arduino.Open();
        }          
    }

    //This never fires==================
    private void arduino_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        receivedText = arduino.ReadExisting();           
    }

    public void CloseMC()
    {
        if (arduino.IsOpen)
        {
            arduino.Close();
            arduino.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Form I call the text from Arduino like this: (I have a button (Button1), a combobox for selecting the COM port (comboBox1) and a textBox on the Form)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialComm arduino = new SerialComm();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        //Arduino
        arduino.InitialiseSerial();
        String[] portList = arduino.portList;
        foreach (String COM in portList)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(COM);
        }

        if (portList.Length > 0)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[0];
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "No microcontroller found!";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arduino.StartMC(serialPort1, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        //as the DataReceived never fires arduino.receivedData stays null
        if (arduino.receivedData != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(arduino.receivedData);
            }
        }        
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        arduino.CloseMC();
    }
}
```

Do you see any reason why the event handler doesn't trigger?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Best Regards,
Peter

Comment: Have you tried enabling RTS in addition to DTR?

Comment: *"I wrote a program for the Arduino which prints"* - mistake could be in there.

Comment: DataReceived works asyncron, but when you start sending your data, you stay in your method. Thus you never give a chance that the event can trigger. You have to end your click method. And then, for an easy solution, use a Timer and try to receive data.

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer, and thank you for the help. Dieters solution worked. Setting RTS and DTR didn't make any difference.